# Highlight specific pixels in a canvas element

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

I currently have a canvas for users to draw on that is positioned above another canvas element with an image rendered in it. When a user draws on the canvas, the data of the newly drawn mark is compared to the corresponding pixel data in the image. If the rgba values are within a certain threshold, the canvas pixel is changed to be opaque, otherwise it is removed. The goal is to highlight only certain parts of the drawing canvas so that only specific pixels within the image threshold are highlighted. However, I cannot get the drawing marks to *stick* to the canvas so to speak. The canvas data is updated and then set which should save the changes. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/small-star-sqrjv

The comparison happens in a function called `highlightImagePixels` located at the bottom of the JavaScript file.

I'm also trying to avoid lag and slowdown from loading the entire pixel data array. The goal is to only select the pixel data that was drawn on.

Comment: To me it looks like you're creating a new "new_data" variable every time the mouse move function is fired. Try declaring that variable outside the function? (Or possibly the other new_canvas_data). What it's doing is overwriting your previous pixel data with every mouse move.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I just moved that functionality to be inside the `onmouseup` function but I'm still seeing the same issue. Maybe you're right, the scope is the problem and it needs to be outside the event handler functions.

Comment: Pretty sure that's the case. If you find it is, let me know and I'll write up an answer to that effect?